# Cascading DropDownLists - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm hoping someone can help me with the below issue, which is likely very basic but I'm still learning MVC 3.0 (and coding in general).

I'm getting a **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String** error within my controller when attempting to load data into my city DropDownList based on the value in the state DropDownList.

I'm hoping I'm just missing something basic. The **int id = int.Parse(state_id)** line within the **JsonResult getCity** call is throwing the error.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.sessionName = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyName"].ToString();
        var compID = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyAccountID"].ToString();
        ViewBag.companyID = compID;

        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select State", Value = "Default State" });
        var states = (from c in simpleDB.simpleState select c).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = states[i].stateFull, Value = states[i].Id.ToString() });
            }
        ViewData["states"] = list;//data for DropdownList State

        List<SelectListItem> list1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select City", Value = "Default City" });
        ViewData["cities"] = list1;//data for Dropdownlist City
        return View();

    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getCity(string state_id)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(state_id);
        var myData = (from m in simpleDB.simpleCity where m.simpleStateId == id select new { text = m.cityFull, value = m.Id });

        return this.Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the full code for my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
```

{

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#StateId').change(function () {
        var state_id = $(this).val(); //get State ID when select value change

        $.getJSON("/SPServiceLocation/getCity/" + state_id, {},

    function (myData) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + myData[i].value + '">' + myData[i].text + '</option>';
        }
        $("#CityId").html();
        $("#CityId").html(options);
    });
    });
});
</script>  

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Step 4: Service Areas</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SPCompanyAccountID, new { @Value = ViewBag.companyID })


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("state", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["states"], new { id = "StateId", @class = "chzn-select" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field" id="SP_SelectCity">
        @Html.DropDownList("city", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["cities"], new { id = "CityId", @class = "chzn-select" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

I've looked at this Controller and View code for a few hours now, and just don't know what the issue might be. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: put an alert in your JS right after you set your state_id variable - alert(state_id) and ensure you are actually grabbing the value.  Also if you do not have a route setup for /SPServiceLocation/getCity/StateId, you will need to use the normal method of passing the parameter (/SPServiceLocation/getCity?state_id=MD)

Comment: go through my tutorials   [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where to start. Looking at this code I really I don't where to start. I could write libraries of books about how bad this code is. But for starters:

```
public JsonResult getCity(string state_id)
```

should be:

```
public JsonResult getCity(string id)
```

This should probably fix your error. Or maybe not. Who knows. Try.

Let me just enumerate a couple of things that strike me directly when I look at your code (and I just did a single glance at it):

- `@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))` - Ermmm what did you mean with this? There's no such overload. You are invoking this overload: `public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object routeValues);`. Probably you meant `@using (Html.BeginForm())`?
- Returning a view without passing a model to it: `return View();` and yet seemingly using a strongly typed view
- `ViewBag.XXX` instead of using a view model
- `list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select State", Value = "Default State" });` instead of using the proper overload of the DropDownListFor helper allowing you to add a default value as third argument
- A horrible hardcoded url in your javascript: `$.getJSON("/SPServiceLocation/getCity/" + state_id`instead of using Url helpers
- String concatenations to manipulate the DOM: `options += '<option value="' + myData[i].value + '">' + myData[i].text + '</option>';`
- `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SPCompanyAccountID, new { @Value = ViewBag.companyID })` doesn't do what you think it does. You cannot override the value attribute. This simply generates 2 value attributes on your hidden field: one with capital `V` and one with lowercase `v`.
- A line of javascript code that only its author could understand what its doing: `$("#CityId").html();`
- Not respected C#/.NET naming conventions for properties: `model => model.state`. In .NET standard conventions dictate that property names should start with a capital letter
- ...

---

Yeah, basically I would start over from scratch. Here's an alternative approach that I would recommend, using view models: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459084/29407

Comment: @AdamD, ohhh I have seen much worse than that. I do lots of code reviews. I actually do code reviews for living. And believe me, this is sugar compared to what I have seen :-)

Comment: Let me take a look at these comments and see what I can do to fix things up. This is literally my first ASP.NET project so certainly starting over may be an option.

Comment: Can you explain why you emphasize changing "state_id" to "id" ?