# Strategy for dynamically loading control data based on other other controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding a good answer to this.
Since it will be a common occurrence in my first MVC application, I'd like to get it right.

A simple case would be two dropdownlists. The first is populated, the other is not. When the first one changes, I need to dynamically load data into the second.

Coming from WebForms, I'd hook up to the change event of the first dropdown, check its value and populate the other in a postback. If I wanted AJAX like behavior, I'd have a WCF service somewhere in the project, and make JQuery calls to that.

I'm tempted to do the same thing here, except I feel that creating a webservice for this kind of bypasses my controller and view model. Plus, I'm not required to load asynchronously here.

So what is the right way to do this? So far I've heard web services, partial views, postbacks, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cascading drop-downs in MVC 3 Razor view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458970/cascading-drop-downs-in-mvc-3-razor-view)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think to search the term 'cascading'

Answer (score 0):

I'd totally go with ajax and jquery. Using the method $.ajax() with a $(.selector).change() event. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you have the reference on the .ajax() method.