# Second DDL not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, cascadingdropdown

> good day, why my second DDL do not fire when I select the Parent dropdown list.
>   Also can anyone elaborate the script and the **[ 0]** in the View beside **m=>m.StateModel**
>
> And for the last question, how can I make this DDL dynamic, How can I populate it using database data?

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Kaskid.Models
{

    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public List<State> StateModel { get; set; }
        public SelectList FilteredCity { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kaskid.Models;

namespace Kaskid.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            CountryModel objCountryModel = new CountryModel();
            objCountryModel.StateModel = new List<State>();
            objCountryModel.StateModel = GetAllState();
            return View(objCountryModel);
        }

         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCityByStateId(int stateId)
        {
            List<City> objCity = new List<City>();
            objCity = GetAllcity().Where(m => m.StateId == stateId).ToList();
            SelectList obgcity = new SelectList(objCity, "Id", "CityName", 0);
            return Json(obgcity);

        }

        public List<State> GetAllState()
        {
            List<State> objState = new List<State>();
        objState.Add(new State {Id = 0,StateName="Select State"});
        objState.Add(new State {Id = 1,StateName = "State 1"});
        objState.Add(new State {Id = 2, StateName="State 2"});
        objState.Add(new State {Id = 3, StateName="State 3"});
         return objState; 

        }

        public List<City> GetAllcity()
        {
        List<City> objCity = new List<City>();
        objCity.Add(new City{Id = 1,StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-1" });
        objCity.Add(new City{Id = 2,StateId=2,CityName = "City2-1"});
        objCity.Add(new City{Id = 3,StateId=4,CityName="City4-1"});
        objCity.Add(new City{Id = 4,StateId=1,CityName="City1-2"});
        return objCity;
        }


    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Kaskid.Models.CountryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script language="javascript">
    function GetCity(_stateId) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $('#ddlcity').html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Home/GetCityByStaeId/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { stateid: _stateId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $('#ddlcity').html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
<h4>
    MVC3 Cascading Dropdown List Using Jquery</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm("", ""))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateModel[0].Id, new SelectList(Model.StateModel, "Id", "StateName"), new { @id = "ddlstate", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity" style="width: 200px">
    </select>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo:

```
var url = "/Home/GetCityByStaeId/";
```

But your controller action is called `GetCityByStateId` and not `GetCityByStaeId`. Also you may take a look at a [`similar example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459084/29407) I once wrote where you could take some ideas about improving your code.

Comment: Thanks Darin!
^_^

Can you explain the javascript here in this project, and can you give me a link how can I make it dynamic by populating DDL using Database data.