# Cascading Combo JSON request not triggering success function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, combobox

I have two combo boxes: one for Clients, and one for Projects. The idea is that when the Client is selected, the Projects combo is then populated. In my MVC code, the combos simply look like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.ClientID, New SelectList(Model.Clients, "ClientID", "Name"), New With {.id = "SelectedClientID"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.ProjectID, Enumerable.Empty(Of SelectListItem), New With {.id = "SelectedProjectID"})
```

Where the Client combo has an ID of `SelectedClientID` and the Project combo has an ID of `SelectedProjectID`.

My problem is my javascript, which triggers an action in my controller when a Client is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedClientID').change(function () {
            var selectedClientID = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProjects")', { ClientID: selectedClientID }, function (projects) {
                var projectsSelect = $('#SelectedProjectId');
                projectsSelect.empty();
                $.each(projects, function (index, project) {
                    projectsSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', project.ProjectID)
                            .text(project.Name)
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>


Function GetProjects(ClientID As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return Json(db.ppProjects.Where(Function(c) c.ClientID = ClientID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

This code is mostly taken from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458970/cascading-drop-downs-in-mvc-3-razor-view). When I debug, I select a Client from the Client combo. This triggers the `.change` function. The `GetProjects` Action is correctly called and returns its JSON. But then the javascript just stops. It never makes it to the code afterwards, it skips all of the success function, `function(projects)`.

What could be causing this to happen?

I have also tried replacing my `$.getJSON` line with a **synchronous** call like so:

```
$.ajax({ datatype: "json", url: "GetProjects", data: { ClientID: selectedClientID}, async: false }).done(function (projects) {
```

but with the same results, success code gets skipped still.

Comment: Attach a `.fail()` / `error()` callback and inspect the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Try using `done()` instead of the success callback:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProjects")', { ClientID: selectedClientID })
        .done(function (projects) {
                var projectsSelect = $('#SelectedProjectId');
                projectsSelect.empty();
                $.each(projects, function (index, project) {
                    projectsSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', project.ProjectID)
                            .text(project.Name)
                    );
                });
            });
```

Comment: And how would that help? The end result would be the same.

Comment: Ya, no luck, still skips everything.