# Issues With Cascading Dropdowns Using MVC4 and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've researched this problem extensively and cannot figure out what is wrong.  I am trying to implement cascading dropdowns using MVC4 and Jquery for a page that I have, and no matter what solution I use online, my ActionResult parameter is always null.

Here's the Javascript which gets called just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clientnames').on('change', function (e) {

    // Retrieve the filter url from the data-filter-url attribute
    var filterUrl = $(this).attr('data-filter-url');

    // Grab the id of the selected item
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
    window.alert("filterurl:" + filterUrl + "    selectedID:" + selectedId);

    // Grab the container that should be updated
    var updateContainer = $(this).attr('data-update-container');

    // Grab the id of new dropdown
    var dataUpdateId = $(this).attr('data-update-id');

    var completeUrl = filterUrl + selectedId;

    $.get(completeUrl, function (r) {

        // Load Partial View using the URL from the data-filter-url attribute
        $(updateContainer).html(r);

        // This would be used if you wanted to trigger the new dropdown to filter another
        if (dataUpdateId != null) {
            // Trigger the change event after it is loaded
            $(dataUpdateId).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

Controller function, this is getting called but the value not successfully passed in:

```
 public ActionResult ImportList(string selectedId)
     {
         //DO COOL STUFF
     }
```

And the view:

> ```
>  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Clients.DropdownItems, 
>          new SelectList(Model.Clients.DropdownItems, "ItemID","ItemName"),
>                         new
>                         {
>                             @class = "clientnames",
>                             data_filter_url = Url.Content("~/import/importlist/"),
>                             data_update_container = ".dropdown-container",
>                             data_update_id = "#SecondItemID"
>                         }
> )
> ```

I am pretty much following the advice on this page here: http://www.sidecreative.com/Blog/Entry/Cascading-dropdown-lists-with-MVC4-and-jQuery

Although I've tried a few different solutions, and everytime the value is still null.  I'm pretty new to MVC and Jquery, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the selected value like this:

```
$('.clientnames').on('change', function (e) {

    // Retrieve the filter url from the data-filter-url attribute
    var filterUrl = $(this).attr('data-filter-url');

    // Grab the id of the selected item
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
    window.alert("filterurl:" + filterUrl + "    selectedID:" + selectedId);

    // Grab the container that should be updated
    var updateContainer = $(this).attr('data-update-container');

    // Grab the id of new dropdown
    var dataUpdateId = $(this).attr('data-update-id');

    $.get(filterUrl, { selectedId: selectedId }, function (r) {

        // Load Partial View using the URL from the data-filter-url attribute
        $(updateContainer).html(r);

        // This would be used if you wanted to trigger the new dropdown to filter another
        if (dataUpdateId != null) {
            // Trigger the change event after it is loaded
            $(dataUpdateId).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

Your controller action takes a parameter called `selectedId`, and notice how this is passed in the `$.get` function:

```
$.get(filterUrl, { selectedId: selectedId }, function (r) {
    ...
});
```

You might also checkout the [`following post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459084/29407) for other examples of implementing cascading droipdowns in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This fixed the null issue.  Was there a recent change in jquery?  I don't know why every example I saw did not have it like this.  I'll look into the post you linked as well to hopefully get this cascading dropdown working.