# Cascade Dropdown Javascript Errors (object doesn't support property)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm trying to implement cascading dropdowns in MVC4 using Jquery.  I've been through countless examples and have yet to find a solution that works.  I am trying the solution that is listed on [Cascading drop-downs in MVC 3 Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458970/cascading-drop-downs-in-mvc-3-razor-view/4459084#4459084)

But I keep getting the Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cascade'

Here's my code.

Javascript Function:

```
   (function ($) {
    $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
        var defaults = {};
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                var params = {};
                params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
                $.getJSON(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                    opts.childSelect.empty();
                    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                        opts.childSelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', item.Id)
                                .text(item.Name)
                        );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you're supposed to simply link it up on the View like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ClientId').cascade({
            url: '@Url.Action("ImportList")',
        paramName: 'clientProjectName',
        childSelect: $('#ImportId')
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    Client:
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClientId, new SelectList(Model.ClientProjects, "ClientProjectName", "ClientProjectName"))
</div>

<div>
    Imports: 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ImportId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
</div>
```

I just want a quick, easy way to get Cascading Dropdowns working, but everything I have tried seems to not work.  I am pretty new to MVC4 and javascript so any full explanations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the cascade function in an external javascript file?  If so are you making sure to include it on your view or layout?

Comment: View the source of the page and make sure all the scripts are there and included in the correct order on the page.